# Запуск Perl-скрипта в Windows

Tags: perl

Добрый день!
Есть [Perl-скрипт](http://rghost.ru/36942476), котопый необходимо запустить, используя ActivePerl (только perl.exe и perl514.dll). Не знаю, как это и реализовать.

Perl-скрипт для работы использует [JPEGTran](http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/jpegtran/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по скрипту - ничего сложного в нем нету. Я-бы порекомендовал попробовать [tinyperl](http://tinyperl.sourceforge.net/), проект старый, но вполне работоспособный. Да, в комплекте нету [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/), так что придется скопировать файл `Slurp.pm` в `lib\File\`

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Не могли бы вы подсказать, а куда надо положить jpegtran, а то он не запускается (лежит в папке со скриптом)?

Не хотели бы вы стать участником моего проекта - Image Catalyst
http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=4&topic=4263

Comment: Запуск `jpegtran` происходит в 25 и 53 строке скрипта. Там возможно следует добавить `.exe` или прописать полный путь.

P.S. Не забываем про то что использование символа разделителя путей под DOS-like OS. Правильное так:

    "С:\\path\\to\\jpegtran.exe"

Comment: А можно сделать используя относительный путь?
пусть jpegtran  будет в папке с jpegrescan

И еще одна проблема, так как я использую Slurp, он использует другие библиотеки, а в свою очередь другие и т.д. Можно ли как получить список нужных мне скриптов, чтобы не тянуть в свой проект все скрипты? Или как можно избавится от Slurp?

Comment: Все модули которые нужны для `Slurp` есть в комплекте поставки `tinyperl` в lib.zip, там в принципе для работы нужно `tinyperl.exe`, `perl58.dll` и `lib.zip`, последний можно распаковать добавить что нужно и запаковать обратно.
Путь к `jpegtran` можно прописать и отностительный, просто тут есть всякие тонкости откуда этот путь считать. Но все проходимо.

Comment: У меня при запуске скрипта через tinyperl выдает разные ошибка в строчках. Как вы сказали добавил Slurp
А если я запускаю через ActivePerl, то проект не находит jpegtran.
А можно вообще избавится от Slurp, или как можно сделать, чтобы я получил список библиотек, которые нужны?
Мы не могли перенести наше общение на почту - lorents17@mail.ru
А дынный вопрос, я бы закрыл бы здесь.

Я был бы рад если бы вы присоединились к моему проекту

Comment: OK. Письмо на e-mail отправил.

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуй lorents. Я не в курсе что есть JPEGTran, но сам делаю обычно так. Пишу в NotePad++ скрипт, затем тыкаю на вкладке правой кнопкой, выскакивает меню. Выбираю пункт "Полный путь к файлу". Затем нажимаю F5 -> набираю в окне cmd -> в открывшейся командной строке клацаю правой кнопкой мыши и туа появляется адрес к скрипту. Последнее действие - нажимаю Enter. Если не получится вставить адрес в ком строку мышкой, ткни правой кнопкой в верхнее синее поле -> правая кнопка мыши -> свойства -> вкладка общие -> ставим галочку на "быстрая вставка". Перезапускаем ком строку.

Comment: Простите, а какое это имеет отношение к моему вопросу?
Я умею работать с командной строкой.

Comment: Тогда я наверно просто не правильно понял Вас. Мне подумалось, что вообще не получается его запустить. Еще раз пардон

Comment: Ситуация другая, если я запускаю скрипт через perl.exe, то в строке use File::Slurp; происходит ошибка, как я понимаю, это из-за того что нет библиотеки, как ее прикрутить не знаю?

Comment: Если честно, то у меня у самого тока сейчас получилось запустить из Perl.exe. Скрипт начал выполняться после того как я заменил в адресе к скрипту символ обратной косой черты на символ прямой.

Comment: Не совсем вас понял, можете привести пример, как вы вели?

Answer (score 1):

поставьте джентельменский набор
деневр denwer.ru
поднимите сервер и запускайте что хотите

Comment: Денвер ставил, но вот как запустить скрипт не знаю.
Если не ошибаюсь, то за работу perl в денвере отвечает улита miniperl.

Comment: Мне по идеи нужен denwer с расширением ActivePerl 5.8, с там же успехом у могу установить просто ActivePerl.
Мне надо сделать без установки дополнений.

Comment: если вы хотите локально работать через браузер, тоставьте деневр.
для работы перла там надо дополнительно скачать его расширение http://www.denwer.ru/packages/perl.html.

если через браузер работать не надо, то работайте через консоль (команда cmd)

Comment: Смотрите, моя цель, сделать итоговый размер минимальным, по этой причине, мне просто надо использовать те скрипты которые необходимы мне, ничего лишнего.

Все это надо для моего проекта - Image Catalyst

Comment: Как я понимаю, мне нужен ActivePerl
bin\perl.exe
bin\perl514.dll
lib\какие именно библиотеки мне нужны я не знаю.
Знаю, что нужен File-Slurp, а что еще надо?

Comment: а что еще вам скажет скрипт.
если что то надо, то он начент ругаться =)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы исключить модуль File::Slurp, можно заменить его функции, например, вот такими:

```
sub read_file {
    my ($file_name) = @_;

    # При ошибке открытия файла возвращаем undef
    open my $FH, '<', $file_name or return;
    my $data;
    {
        local $/;
        $data = <$FH>;
    }
    close $FH;
    return $data;
}

sub write_file {
    my ($file_name, @data) = @_;

    # При ошибке возвращаем undef
    open my $FH, '>', $file_name or return;
    print $FH @data;
    close $FH;
    return 1;
}
```

После добавления этих функций в скрипт можно удалить строку 'use File::Slurp;'

Впрочем, я посоветовал бы всё же рассмотреть вариант установки этого модуля, поскольку наличие готовых модулей для решения практически любой задачи - одна из сильнейших сторон Perl - если начинать на нём программировать, то нужно уметь пользоваться этим преимуществом. Тем более, что устанавливается модуль элементарно штатной утилитой [из репозитория ppm](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/File-Slurp/)

Comment: готовые модули это сильные стороны, не спорю.
Просто в моем случаи мне надо запустить скрипты без установки перл (только perl.exe и perl514.dll) и с минимальным количеством модулем.